# Edit and storing json after fetching ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic2

I fetching a json this way:

```
this.http.get('http://someaddress.json')
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(
    data => { ... }
);
```

Now I would like to change some of the data and store it locally and after that I want to read the stored data.
What is best practice for doing it?

Comment: You can use `Storage` http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/

Comment: no json example there...

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(public storage: Storage){}
save(){
  this.http.get('http://someaddress.json').map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => { this.storage.set('address',data) });
}
```

//use it like

```
this.storage.get('address');
```